# Google Charts using CSV Data: $.csv is undefined?

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv, charts

So I have a working google chart that uses a CSV file, parses the CSV data as a string into an array, and uses the array as the datatable.

I actually asked a question and answered it myself [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142071/google-chart-with-csv-data-columns-error).

That link will show you a full chunk of code that I used in my full working website.

I intended to just pull the script from the test file and drop it into my website, but now that I've moved it over and included the scripts I needed, I'm getting an error as:

```
Type Error: $.csv is undefined
```

Here is the code where $.csv is being utilized **(var arrayData)**, this is a function for drawing the chart

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> // load the visualisation API
      google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'controls'] });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
       $.get("Thornton.M2.csv", function(csvString) {
          // transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
          var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

          // this new DataTable object holds all the data
          var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
          // CAPACITY - En-route ATFM delay - YY - CHART
          var crt_ertdlyYY = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
             chartType: 'LineChart',
             containerId: 'crt_ertdlyYY',
             dataTable: data,
             options:{
                width: 450, height: 160,
                title: 'EU-wide en-route ATFM delays (year to date)',
                titleTextStyle : {color: 'grey', fontSize: 11},
             }
          });
          crt_ertdlyYY.draw();
       });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization)
    </script>

    </head>

      <body>

        <div id="crt_ertdlyYY"></div>

      </body>
```

This example works fully as you can see from the link I had posted before hand, if you wanted to test it. But now that I pull it into my main site the .csv calls do not recognize. I also have 2 other google charts on this page that still work properly so it's isolated to this issue. I'm very new to google charts and pretty confused here!

Comment: As the error states, `$.csv` is "not defined" (ie. `$.csv === undefined` is true). Go find out where it *"should"* come from, and ensure it is loaded/assigned prior to usage. I suspect there is a 404 preventing the associated library from loading - check the browser network log.

Comment: looks like you didn't move one of the files --> `jquery.csv.min.js`

Comment: @WhiteHat I have the two test files in the same file as jquery.csv.min.js? The files didn't move between testing and my import script tags are the exact same :/